# Radio button unchecked with jQuery won't check again

Tags: jquery, radio-button, prop

I have modal with four radio inputs - `onchange` modal hides and further logic is executed. Modal can be shown several times, so as it hides suddenly after change I need to remove `checked` attribute to allow user to choose the same option next time (click on `checked` radio won't fire `onchange`).

Most approved answers concerning manipulating radio input with JS suggest to do it with jQuery:

`$('.modal input:radio').prop('checked', false)`

Indeed after calling above there is no `checked` attribute in HTML, but radio is checked anyway - it can't be checked again and image representing it looks "selected". On the other hand, code below does it's job:

`document.getElementById('modal-radio').checked = false;`
`document.getElementById('modal-radio-2').checked = false;`

I wonder if it's kind of a bug or I don't get something?

EDIT: when I call jQuery `prop('checked', false)` on every single input, it also works. But documentation says that `prop` can set property of whole collection.

Comment: *Indeed after calling above there is no checked attribute in HTML* - Property and attribute though look similar but are different, property is something internal to the HTML control (like some private member in OOP), the behavior of which depends on.Attribute on the other hand is the "visible" HTML declaration from which the control get its instruction on how to initialize itself; what properties and what values.After page rendering the role of attributes is pretty much done though browsers try hard to keep them in sync with properties.

Comment: @Viney - exactly that's why I use `prop()` method and not `attr()`.